# radio button deselcted but form still appearing?

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button

I've got a form that I want the user to fill out, it contains two radio buttons and when each one is selected, it brings up further options for the user to fill out - however when I click on one radio button, the select another, the previous form information (that is associated with the other button) is still there - I'm not sure how to code it so that when the button is deselected, the form fields also disappear along with it.

The code is below, but I also included a [jfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/FV5KN/) so that you can see it in action.

form

```
<form action="" method="post" id="contactForm"> <strong><label for="box1" id="box1_label">name</label></strong>

    <br />
    <input type="text" name="box1" class="tentry" id="namae" tabindex="1" />
    <br />
    <div class="error" id="box1_error">
        <label for="box1">this field is required!</label>
    </div>  <strong>email</strong>

    <br />
    <input type="text" class="tentry" name="box2" id="tegami" tabindex="2" />
    <br />
    <div class="error" id="box2_error">
        <label for="box2">this field is required!</label>
    </div>  <strong>lets...</strong>

    <br />
    <input name="radio1" type="radio" id="client" value="work together" tabindex="3" />
    <label for="client">work together
        <label>&nbsp;
            <input name="radio1" type="radio" id="chatter" value="chit-chat" tabindex="4" />
            <label for="chatter">chat</label>
            <div class="error" id="radio1_error">
                <label for="radio1">you must select a button!</label>
            </div>
            <div id="clientBox" style="display: none;"> <strong><label for="website" id="website_label">website</label></strong>

                <br />
                <input type="text" class="tentry" name="website" id="web" value="http://" />
                <br />  <strong><label for="info" id="info_label">tell me about your project!</label></strong>

                <br />
                <textarea name="info" rows="6" cols="35" id="infoArea">so what do you need?</textarea>
            </div>
            <div id="chatterBox" style="display: none;">    <strong><label for="chatter" id="chatter_label">let's talk!</label></strong>

                <br />
                <textarea name="chatter" rows="6" cols="35" id="infoArea">what's on your mind?</textarea>
            </div>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="Send" />
</form>
```

jQuery

```
//Display extra forms on radio button press
$('#client').click(function () {
    if ($('#client').is(':checked')) {
        $('#clientBox').show();
    } else {
        $('#clientBox').hide();
    }
});
$('#chatter').click(function () {
    if ($('#chatter').is(':checked')) {
        $('#chatterBox').show();
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you

```
$('#client').click(function () {
    $('#client').is(':checked')) {
        $('#clientBox').show();
        $('#chatterBox').hide();
    }
});
$('#chatter').click(function () {
    if ($('#chatter').is(':checked')) {
        $('#chatterBox').show();
        $('#clientBox').hide();
    }
});
```